# RubyMine JavaScript "cannot resolve directory"

Tags: javascript, html, directory, rubymine, resolve

Sorry if this is a simple question I am VERY new to Ruby.

I am trying to use a template for my website. I copied all of the files into the proper folders. However when I run my website it is not using any of the javascript files.

This is the problem in the html file.

```
<script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.dropotron.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.scrolly.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.onvisible.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/skel.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/util.js"></script>
<!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="assets/js/ie/respond.min.js"></script><!     [endif]-->
<script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
```

It says "cannot resolve file" on all of these lines.
I am sure that require tree . is in the application.js and I have also tried copying the path and reference and pasting it between the quotation marks. I also tried to use

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "jquery.min" %>
```

And this is what the head of my html looks like

```
<head>

<title>HSA</title>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>

</head>
```

I am also having a similar issue in my main.css on the line

```
background-image: url("../../images/header.jpg");
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like some [asset pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) issues. I suggest you adjust the direct references to the `.js` files and the `.jpg` from your code asset calls are used instead.

To include jquery library you are better off using `jquery-rails` gem. If you did not change it in your `Gemfile` it should be already there.

you need this line in your application.js file:

```
//= require jquery
```

because you seem to be using a `/js` subfolder, you must tell rails to look into this folder. Navigate to the folder `your-app/config/initializers` and edit the file `assets.rb`. You should add this line there so the per-compiler knows about your custom folder:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += ['js/*']
```

for retrieving pictures in a css file, you should change this line:

```
background-image: url("../../images/header.jpg");
```

to this:

```
background-image: url("<%= asset_path 'header.jpg' %>");
```

and rename your `.css` files to `.css.erb`

good luck!